# Python:how to shutdown a thread created by threading module

Tags: python, multithreading

when i learn multi-threads of Python, i meet some trouble. i use threading module.here is my code.

```
class thread_1(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self,num):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.num = num

def run(self):
    while self.num >0:
        print('1')
        self.num -= 1

def main():
    thread_test = thread_1(10)
    thread_test.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when i run it on the idle, the thread appears not to exit.

the cursor just blink and don't exit on the idle